# Canvas as ImageView/Bitmap

Tags: java, android

I cant get my head around this problem I have. I have 2 images which were added to a canvas and will be treated as one object, now I need to return this canvas as bitmap/drawable, since
Here is code how I added 2 bitmaps into a canvas

```
Bitmap image1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() ,R.drawable.icon1);
Bitmap image2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() R.drawable.icon2);
Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
Rect dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
dstRect.offset(15, 0);      
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, srcRect, dstRect, null);

        dstRect.offset(image.getWidth(), 0);    

        canvas.drawBitmap(image2, srcRect, dstRect, null);
       //return???????????
```

Please someone help.
Tnx in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a Bitmap to draw into.

```
Bitmap image1=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() ,R.drawable.icon1);
Bitmap image2=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() R.drawable.icon2);
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetWidth, targetHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);//Create the canvas to your image
Rect srcRect = new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
Rect dstRect = new Rect(srcRect);
dstRect.offset(15, 0);      
canvas.drawBitmap(image, srcRect, dstRect, null); //draw on it
dstRect.offset(image.getWidth(), 0);    
canvas.drawBitmap(image2, srcRect, dstRect, null);
return result;//result will have the drawed images from the canvas
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Was trying to solve this all day! Thank you once more :) !

Comment: Another question I have for you Marcos, basically my app will allow infinite set of images to be displayed by adding one at a time to a canvas. My app works fine, however it crashes when I add up to 7 images (each of them is as twice as the screen of the phone). I believe it is due to the memory usage. Is there any way to free the memory/distroy the images which have already been attached to the result Bitmap?

Comment: @Alanagh The only precaution you can have is to .recycle() the Bitmaps you already drawed in your Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Where did you get the canvas from? If from a bitmap, then that obj will now have whatever you drew on the canvas applied to it.

Canvas is just a way to draw onto a bitmap or drawable that it is backed by. So if you create a Bitmap called result and then get your canvas from that you can just return that.

As in..

```
Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
...do your stuff...
return result;
```

Comment: I was drawing it in onDraw method, and got lost afterwards :). Thanks for your prompt reply and explanation!